# LocalContextHandler usage

Tags: spring, internationalization

I am very new to LocalContexHandler. I have read about it. From what I understood it is used to retrieve locale information in a java application.

I am passing the locale from the url as follows:
    `url?lang = fr`

When I am trying to retrieve the locale in java application as follows:
    `Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();`

It is giving null value. Can someone help me understand it's usage or is there any other alternative for the same?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass locale in URL you must register `LocaleChangeInterceptor` interceptor and create `LocaleResolver` bean. For example `SessionLocaleResolver` stores chosen locale in session. Then `LocaleContextHolder#getLocale` will return not-null value. Take a look in Spring documentation to section [Using locales](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-localeresolver). Below you can see basic Java configuration for you example.

If you want just use `LocaleContextHolder` you have to call `LocaleContextHolder#setLocale` from your code before calling `LocaleContextHolder#getLocale`. It's just simple holder class that stores `LocaleContext` in `ThreadLocal` variable.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  // Rest of Web MVC configuration omitted

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    super.addInterceptors(registry);

    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
  }

  @Bean
  public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale("fr");

    return sessionLocaleResolver;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    interceptor.setParamName("lang");

    return interceptor;
  }

}
```

Comment: I added the locale resolver in my application-context.xml file  <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>                                                       after adding this I just added  LocaleContextHolder.getLocale(); in my application. But it's still not fetching the current locale.

Comment: SessionLocaleResolver is storing locale information in the session. But in my java application I am not using any request,response or session object. Then how can I retrieve locale information from it?

Comment: You wrote `I am passing the locale from the url as follows: url?lang = fr` so I think you are using request,response and session in your app. Please specify question and put example of your not working solution.